# MySQL to find all tables with a Full Text indexed column in them

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I need to run a repair on all the tables in all my databases on my MySQL5 server because I have updated the MySQL full text search stopwords file.

Is there a query or command I can run to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you just need to query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`STATISTICS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statistics-table.html) table:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE index_type LIKE 'FULLTEXT%'
```

Comment: Thanks that does the trick. I have added an additional parameter to the select portion of the query `CONCAT('REPAIR TABLE \`', TABLE_SCHEMA, '\`.\`', TABLE_NAME, '\` QUICK;')`